# How to define a field in an object is unique in openapi?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

I have this api documentation written in OpenAPI 3.0.3

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: 'MyTitle'
  description: Specification for Bear Store

servers:
  - url: https://development.example.com/v1
    description: Development Server

paths:
  '/v1/bears':
    get:
      description: Requests a lists all the bears
      summary: List of bears request
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List of Bears
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    id:
                      type: string
                      format: uuid
                    name:
                      type: string
```

I have a Bear object that has `id`, and `name` properties. I want to define that id field is a unique field. How can I define this in OpenAPI 3?

Comment: _define that id field is unique_ How could a static UI determine if an id is unique? Only the API can say "no that id is used"

Comment: This is the specification of the API. I need to define the specification in this document. I need to define that 'id is unique'. How is it defined in OpenAPI

Comment: You can write a description to explain the uniqueness. But OpenApi has no concept of a field that can only take unique values.

Comment: @abdusco you should post your comment as an answer because that's the answer.

Comment: @Helen Alright, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenAPI lets you define a field's type and its expected format. But it's not possible for it to ensure its uniqueness.

Uniqueness is a business concern, which might involve non-trivial checks. Therefore, it's outside the scope of OpenAPI/Swagger to formalize such concepts.

However, you can **add a description** to explain the requirement that the field value must be unique, then implement necessary checks in the API to ensure that the value supplied by the client is actually unique.